# T test between two dataframes and grouped by similar rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, broom, hypothesis-test

The title may not be extremely clear but hopefully I can describe it better here. I have two data frames and each one describes monthly spending for different types of customers.  For example, for A customers I have a dataframe like

```
year_month    customer_id     monthly_spending
201301        123             5.50
201301        124             2.30
201301        125             6.80
201302        123             8.30
201302        124             5.60
```

Then I also have a similar dataframe for B customers.  Ideally I want a dataframe where I have the T test results for each month comparing the spending between A customers and B customers.  I can do this using dplyr() and Broom() if all the data is in one dataframe.  Is there a way to do this if I have two dataframes or is it better to merge the two together then do the T test and group_by year_month?

Comment: Do you only have 2 dataframes? If yes, I would simply merge them and do the T test after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Gainz in the comments in concept.  Combining the dataframes is probably the easiest approach.  However, a true merge-type operation, e.g. `left_join()` etc. may not actually be needed; simply using `bind_rows()` can be sufficient.

```
# read data from question
df_A <-
'year_month    customer_id     monthly_spending
201301        123             5.50
201301        124             2.30
201301        125             6.80
201302        123             8.30
201302        124             5.60' %>% 
    str_replace_all('[ ]++', '\t') %>% 
    read_tsv

# simulate more data for customer group "B"
df_B <- 
    df_A %>%    
    mutate(monthly_spending = monthly_spending + rnorm(5))

# combine the dataframes
df_all <-
    bind_rows(list('A' = df_A, 'B' = df_B), .id = 'customer_type')

# use broom to do a tidy t.test()
df_all %>% 
    group_by(year_month) %>%
    do(tidy(t.test(formula = monthly_spending ~ customer_type, 
                   data=.)))
```

The combined dataframe `df_all` here is

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   customer_type year_month customer_id monthly_spending
   <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 A                 201301         123             5.5 
 2 A                 201301         124             2.3 
 3 A                 201301         125             6.8 
 4 A                 201302         123             8.3 
 5 A                 201302         124             5.6 
 6 B                 201301         123             6.25
 7 B                 201301         124             2.63
 8 B                 201301         125             7.04
 9 B                 201302         123             9.11
10 B                 201302         124             5.11
```

The result of doing the t.tests is

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
# Groups:   year_month [2]
  year_month estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low
       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     201301  -0.692       4.87      5.56   -0.341    0.750      3.93    -6.35
2     201302  -0.0453      6.95      7.00   -0.0334   0.979      1.02   -16.4 
# … with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

Comment: I did end up merging the two together - which was the easiest method in the end - but I was also able to get there with the answer you provided as well!